# Saturated measure defined as a supremum of a semifinite measure and countable unions

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Here is what I am working on:

> Suppose that $\mu$ is semifinite. For E in $\overline{M}$, define $\underline{\mu}(E)=\sup\{\mu(A):A$ in $M$ and $A \subseteq E$$\}$. Then $\underline{\mu}$ is a saturated measure on $\overline{M}$ that extends $\mu$.

I know that I need to establish that $\underline{\mu}$ is a measure, and then show that it is a saturated measure. I'm stuck on showing that the measure of a countable union of sets is equal to the sum of their measures. In particular, I know that if I have $\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ S_i$ where each $S_i \epsilon \overline{M}$, and some $S_k$ has $\underline{\mu}(S_k)=∞$, then clearly both the sum and the measure of the union will be $∞$, and if every $S_i$ is in M, then the sum of the measures is clearly the measure of the union since this is the case for the already-established measure $\mu$. I don't know what to do, however, if a few of the $S_i$'s happen to be in $\overline{M}$ but not in $M$. I wish I could just create a sequence of $T_i$ where each $T_i$ is the subset of $S_i$ maximal under the condition that $T_i$ is in M, but the problem is that I don't think the measure of such a $T_i$ under $\mu$ is necessarily the same as $\underline{\mu}(S_i)$ when $S_i$ is not in M since this latter measure is defined as a supremum, and suprema are not necessarily themselves elements of the set they are taken from.

(To be clear, $\overline{M}$ is the set of all locally measurable subsets of $X$, where a set $E ⊆ X$ is called locally measureable if $E ∩ A$ is in $M$ for all $A$ in $M$ such that $μ(A) < ∞$, and a measure is saturated if $M = \overline{M}$ with respect to that measure)

Comment: Suppose you want to show that $\overline{\mu}(E_1\cup E_2)\leq \overline{\mu}(E_1)+\overline{\mu}(E_2)$, where $E_1$, $E_2$ $\in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$, with $E_1\cap E_2=\emptyset$. Suppose there is $A\in \mathcal{M}$, with $\mu(A)=\infty$, such that $A\subset E_1 \cup E_2$. How'd you show the inequality in this case?

Comment: I know I can then say that A intersect E1 and A intersect E2 are disjoint subsets of A whose union is all of A, and both are elements of M, so one of them is necessarily of infinite measure with respect to mu, and also a subset of whichever of E1 or E2 it is an intersection with, so the underline-mu measure of that one must be infinity. But I'm not sure how to apply that idea here.

Comment: My quandary is, whether or not it actually happens, I can imagine that each subset in an increasing chain of subsets of S_k, say adds as little as one element, though this is hyperbole, and increases toward the finite supremum of their measures just a little bit, but none of them actually hit that exact amount. If I could convince myself that some subset of S necessarily has the same measure under mu that S does under underline-mu, I would be done.

Comment: Xindaris, about your first comment, are you sure both are elements of M? I don't think so.

Comment: You need to show that in a semifinite measure space, an infinite-measure set can be "approximated" by ever larger measurable sets contained in it.

Comment: The S_k I'm concerned with isn't of infinite measure because I already covered that case. I'm concerned with the case that some S_k is not in M, but is in overline-M, and has finite measure. Specifically: How do I know that some measurable subset of a finite-measure S_k has the same measure as the supremum of all of them? I'm probably completely missing your point. Are you saying I didn't do the infinite case correctly?

Comment: To my first comment you replied: "I know I can then say that $A\cap E_1$ and $A \cap E_2$ are disjoint subsets of $A$ whose union is all of $A$, and both are elements of $\mathcal{M}$". You don't know if both are elements of $\mathcal{M}$, because locally measurable sets are those whose intersection with any $A$ is in $\mathcal{M}$ *as long as that $A$ has finite measure*. So you missed something in the infinite case. As for your quandary, you don't need the supremum to be reached. Apply the "$\epsilon / 2^k$" technique. See Folland's textbook.

Comment: Would you like me to post the full solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Weltschmerz was trying to point out to me, the proof involves using $\epsilon/2^i$.

If $\underline{\mu}(S_i) < ∞$ for every i, suppose $\epsilon>0$. Since $\underline{\mu}$ is defined as a supremum, for each i there exists a set $T_i \subseteq S_i$ so that $T_i \in M$ and $\underline{\mu}(T_i) = \mu(T_i) = \underline{\mu}(S_i) - \epsilon/2^i$. So

$\sum_{i=1}^∞ \underline{\mu}(S_i)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^∞ (\underline{\mu}(T_i) + \epsilon/2^i)$ $=\sum_{i=1}^∞ \mu(T_i) + \sum_{i=1}^∞ \epsilon/2^i$ $=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ T_i)+\sum_{i=0}^∞ \epsilon/2^{i+1}$ $=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞) T_i + (\epsilon/2)/(1-1/2)$ $=\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ T_i) + \epsilon$.

Since $\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ T_i$ is a subset of $\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ S_i$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and an element of $M$, and $\underline{\mu}(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ S_i)$ $=\sup\{\mu(A):A$ in $M$ and $A \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^∞ S_i\}$, $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ T_i) + \epsilon$ approaches $\underline{\mu}(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ S_i)$ as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$, so $\sum_{i=1}^∞ \underline{\mu}(S_i)$ $=\underline{\mu}(\bigcup_{i=1}^∞ S_i)$, as desired.

(Did I miss anything?)

Answer (score 0):

To me you only demonstrated that $\underline{\mu}(\bigcup S_i) \geq \sum\underline{\mu}(S_i)$. Now you need to show that $\underline{\mu}(\bigcup S_i) \leq \sum\underline{\mu}(S_i)$ and for that you need the semifinite property of $\mu$ for the case where $\exists A \subset \bigcup S_i, A \in {\cal M}$ and $\mu(A) = \infty$ exactly like Weltschmerz was pointing out to you.